# Analyze multiple choice questionnaire with python algorithm

Tags: python, statistics

Hey guys am looking for a steps for analyse questionnaire data that include 5 choose "strongly disagree, disagree, not sure, agree, strongly agree". What are the best steps to make the data ready to use the algorithm with python? The data is ready in excel. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What algorithm? What kind of steps are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with analyzing your data with Explanatory data analysis(EDA)

1. You can do the descriptive analysis which includes Missing Values, 
   Quantile 
   statistics, descriptive statistics, unique counts.
2. You can perform correlation analysis on your data using Pearson correlation.
3. You can also perform qualitative and quantitative analysis.
4. You can also plot distribution histograms to analyze the data distribution.

You can refer pandas-profiling for the EDA

https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling

Based on your EDA you can further proceed with data cleaning and data processing.